# Excel - Correct way of finding sum of Ratios

Tags: excel, statistics

This is more of a statistical question rather than Excel Related.
In the attached image, im trying to find out the ratio of Profit/Sales
and then calculating overall Profit/Sales

Please let me know which one is correct
Refer the image
[Sum of Ratios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkEog.jpg)

Comment: Cross-Validated (http://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be proper forum for your question since you are asking question regarding appropriateness of methods and there is no problem in execution of the methods.

Comment: The one on the right is correct.